# 3 images in a row centered in container

Tags: css, image, html, positioning, center

CSS

```
.contain {
max-width:960px;
text-align:center;
}

.category {
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
float:left;
padding:10px;
}

.category2 {
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
pading:10px;
}
.category3 {
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
float:right;
margin-right:50%;
padding:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
        <div align="center" class="category">
        <img src="gemstoneshomebutton.png" />
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category2">
        <img src="dichroichomebutton.png" />
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category3">
        <img src="filigreehomebutton.png" />

</div>
```

i am trying to align 3 images that are 309 px wide , by 111 px high inside a container div, 
and they don't align center and also the third image jumps down below the other two images.
I've tried to adjust the width of the container and the 3 divs, I've tried tables and changing the width on the actual html with no success.

This is my first time working with divs and i thought they would be easier, perhaps my math is off when assigning widths, or maybe I'm just structuring it all wrong.![here is an example of what i am trying to achieve, the three categories in the picture here.] http://i49.tinypic.com/2r2uqso.jpg

any
and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put `float: left` on all three. Also go watch some screencasts on CSS-Tricks, they'll make your learning process easier :)

Comment: thank you so much, though i just did that, and all it did was put space between the first two divs/images.

Comment: 'Inspect Element' is your friend, use it to troubleshoot positioning issues. My guess is you probably need to adjust the widths, and get rid of that margin. Also important to know is that floating an element makes the `display` property irrelevant.

Comment: `align` attribute is [deprecated in HTML4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2) and [not supported in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-attributes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS

```
.contain {
    max-width:960px;
    text-align:center;
}

.category {
   position:relative;
   display: inline-block;
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div align="center" class="category">
   <img src="gemstoneshomebutton.png" />
</div>
<div align="center" class="category">
   <img src="dichroichomebutton.png" />
</div>
<div align="center" class="category">
   <img src="filigreehomebutton.png" />    
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. It appears that the first div is still over to the side (outside the container) and the third div is still below the other two, after i made these changes.
http://i49.tinypic.com/28mrt4.png see here

Comment: Think that if your images has each 309px width [3*309=927px] and has a padding left and right [(2*10)*3=60)] all three together will have a width of  987px, which is more than 960px. And the last one goes down due to lack of space.

Answer (score 9):

Don't forget to add 'alt' attribute in the img tag! It is especially important for people who a partially sighted or blind.

http://www.myblogsplace.com/images-alt-text

Answer (score 1):

Yes the alt attribute is really important. It is actually used by "screen reader" software so when a person is listening to the content of a webpage, like a blind person, can interact with that specific element. All images should have this attribute so it is accessible.